# Notion of neighborhood in Hall's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

In Hall's Theorem, should we refer to $N(S)$ as $\bigcup_{x \in S}N(x)$ or as $\bigcup_{x \in S}N(x) - S$? I guess that the second definition is the one used in the theorem.

Comment: Generally, $S$ is a subset of the vertices only on one side of the bipartite graph, so your two definitions are equivalent

Comment: This is a circular question, isn't it? You're asking about the definition of the neighborhood $N$ in terms of that definition. Someone who's using a different definition from you would be answering a different question.

Comment: @MishaLavrov He is asking to define $N(S \subseteq V)$ interms of $N(v \in V)$

Comment: @Tuatarian My point is that the question depends entirely on which definition for $N(v)$ you take. (To which my *personal* reaction is "there's no such thing, you meant $N(\{v\})$", but I realize other people make different notational decisions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer "what should $N(S)$ mean in Hall's theorem?" because that's clearly what the question wants to be asking, but I find the notation in the question ambiguous.

There are two options for the statement of Hall's theorem. The first is much more common, but I will include both, because it's more interesting to compare definitions that way.

1. In a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $(X,Y)$, we can say that Hall's condition (for checking if $G$ has an $X$-saturating matching) is that $|N(S)| \ge |S|$ for all $S \subseteq X$. Here, $N(S)$ is defined as the set of all vertices of $G$ which are adjacent to some vertex in $S$; $N(S)$ is necessarily a subset of $Y$. The only clarification we need to make is that vertices of $S$ are not *automatically included* in $N(S)$.
2. In a bipartite graph $G$ wtith bipartition $(X,Y)$, we can say that Hall's condition (for checking if $G$ has a *perfect* matching) is that $|N(S)| \ge |S|$ for all $S \subseteq X \cup Y$. (This is much less common; see exercise 3.1.22 in West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*.) Here, $N(S)$ can still be defined as the set of all vertices of $G$ which are adjacent to some vertex in $S$. Vertices of $S$ are neither automatically included nor automatically excluded from $N(S)$.

In both cases, we can define $N(S)$ to contain every vertex $v \in V(G)$ such that $v$ has a neighbor in $S$, without care for whether $v \in S$ and $v \notin S$. This is also the most common definition of $N(S)$.

Other definitions encountered in graph theory include:

- The set of vertices which have a neighbor in $S$, but are not themselves in $S$; this is common in the study of vertex expansion, where it is *also* commonly denoted $N(S)$. As an alternative, Wikipedia uses the notation $\partial_{\text{out}}(S)$ in the article on [expander graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph). The first and by far more common version of Hall's theorem still holds if we check the condition $|\partial_{\text{out}}(S)| \ge |S|$, because in the first version of Hall's theorem, vertices in $S$ cannot possibly be adjacent. For the second version of Hall's theorem, this condition is too strict.
- The set of vertices with have a neighbor in $S$, or are themselves in $S$. This is more commonly called the *closed neighborhood* of $S$. Notation varies, but $\overline N(S)$ is a common version that distinguishes it from $N(S)$. *Neither* version of Hall's theorem will work with this definition.